# 'mergeDelayError' does not exist in RxJS 5

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I came across this method in RxJS 4 and it seems quite helpful, however I can't seem to find it anywhere in RxJS 5.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/errors.md

Does anyone know if anything in RxJS 5 does similar behavior?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rxjs5 merge and error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738571/rxjs5-merge-and-error-handling). Unfortunately, although this question was asked first, I can't flag the other post as a duplicate, because the other post has an upvoted and accepted answer (even though it's not a complete answer). So I've had to flag this one as duplicate and remove my answer here (was scolded about cross-posting answers). I've answered your question there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a polyfill for it like that.

```js
function mergeDelayError(...sources: Array<Observable<any>>) {
    const final = new Subject();
    const catching = sources.map(obs => obs.pipe(
        catchError(e => {
            if (!final.hasError) {
                final.error(e);
            }
            return EMPTY;
        }),
    ));

    return concat(merge(...catching), final);
}

const o1$ = interval(150).pipe(take(5));
const o2$ = throwError(new Error('woops1'));
const o3$ = throwError(new Error('woops2'));

mergeDelayError(o1$, o2$, o3$).subscribe(
    x => console.log('next:', x),
    e => console.log('error:', e),
    () => console.log('completed'),
);
```

output is

```
[Log] next: – 0
[Log] next: – 1
[Log] next: – 2
[Log] next: – 3
[Log] next: – 4
[Log] error: – Error: woops1
```